# php - smtp pear Mail.php include

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

this may be a simple one but im confused now. I basicly using the same frame work which i built for a previouse project and changing the skin.

I have tried to test the email function but has failed to work, this is the error:

> Warning: require_once()
>   [function.require-once]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect.
>   File(../../../../php/Mail.php) is not
>   within the allowed path(s):
>   (/home/amatoita:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp)

for some reason It seems like im not allowed here???

so i tried

> /usr/lib/php/Mail.php
>
> /home/amatoita/php/Mail.php
>
> /usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php

which threw the following error:

> Failed opening required
>   'Mail/mimePart.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in /home/amatoita/php/Mail/mime.php

can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by following the PEAR install directions at [Mark's Tech Stuff blog](http://markstechstuff.blogspot.com/2009/04/installing-pear-mail-for-php-on-ubuntu.html).

My problem was that the Mail module of pear is not included in a standard Fedora install.

Then I used some code [from the PEAR site](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php).

```
<?php

include 'Mail.php';
include 'Mail/mime.php' ;

$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = '/home/richard/example.php';
$crlf = "\n";
$hdrs = array(
          'From'    => 'you@yourdomain.com',
          'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
          );

$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
$mail->send('postmaster@localhost', $hdrs, $body);

?>
```

Now my email gets sent in HTML just fine. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have that package installed in one of the directories listed in the include_path. That means (most likely), you'd want it to be:

```
/home/amatoita/php/Mail.php
```

and have the mimePart.php in

```
/home/amatoita/php/Mail/mimepart.php
```